# JavaScript FileReader: Ensure variable is populated with multiple asynchronous file reads

Tags: javascript, filereader

Basically, I'm reading local files to display the data contents to the user. The files have a metadata text section followed by a large binary section. The metadata contains vital information needed to correctly parse the binary section. So, the pattern I'm using to parse the file is the following:

1. Get the text and binary offsets
2. Parse metadata and save info about binary parsing
3. Parse the binary data using the info from step 2

I've setup multiple FileReaders to accomplish this, and everything seems to be working. However, during development I had to be careful about how the intermediate data is saved so it was available for the binary parsing step.

Here's the basic code I've created, with the long file parsing details removed for better readability:

```
function setupReader(obj) {
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.addEventListener("loadend", function(evt) {
        ...get start/end locations for text and data sections

        parseText(obj);
        parseData(obj);
    });
    var blob = obj.file.slice(0, 58);
    reader.readAsBinaryString(blob);
}

function parseText(obj) {
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.addEventListener("loadend", function(evt) {
        ...do lots of stuff and record new properties in obj

        // save obj to scope so it's available to parse data section
        $scope.file_obj = obj;
    });

    var blob = obj.file.slice(obj.text_begin, obj.text_end);
    reader.readAsBinaryString(blob);
}

function parseData(obj) {
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.addEventListener("loadend", function(evt) {
        ...populate array in $scope.file_obj from binary data
    });

    var blob = obj.file.slice(obj.data_begin, obj.data_end);
    reader.readAsBinaryString(blob);
}
```

My question is whether this pattern guarantees that `$scope.file_obj` will be available in `parseData()`?

This seems to be the case, however `parseText()` happens quite fast, so I'm not sure if I'm just lucky that it finished in time. I want to be sure I understand the behaviour.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

To ensure that the data is available on the $scope, I would rather call parseData from inside the 'loadend' event handler in parseText. Otherwise, as you say, you might just be lucky.

Best.